# Positioning a relative img in css

Tags: html, css

Im currently learning HTML in school and I'm kinda struggling with positioning an image thats in a div. Heres my html code:

```css
.bild1 {
    position:relative;
    top:500 px;
    max-width:50%;
    max-height:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bild1">
    <img src="http://cms.immoscout24.ch/media/1341/umzug-ostern.jpg">
</div>
```

Does anyone know how I can position a Picture thats relative (it needs to be relative)

Comment: where do you want to position it?

Comment: What are you asking for?

Comment: Relative to what ?

Comment: You are position the div, if you like the position the image relative to the div you should do this .bild1 img{...}

Comment: why you need to add position? any specific reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `top: 500 px;` has a space between `500` and `px`, so it is not accepting it. change it to `top: 500px;`

```css
.bild1 {
    position:relative;
    top: 500px;
    max-width:50%;
    max-height:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bild1">
  <img src="http://cms.immoscout24.ch/media/1341/umzug-ostern.jpg">
</div>
```

If you want the image to receive these properties add `img` after your `.bild1`, like so `.bild1 img { ...`

```css
.bild1 img {
  position:relative;
  top: 500px;
  max-width:50%;
  max-height:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bild1">
  <img src="http://cms.immoscout24.ch/media/1341/umzug-ostern.jpg">
</div>
```

Hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

```css
.bild1{width:200px;height:200px;}
.bild1 img{max-width:100%;}
```

```html
<div class="bild1">
        <img src="http://cms.immoscout24.ch/media/1341/umzug-ostern.jpg">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the position: relative work on the image you need to pass it to the image.

This will bind the css only on the class bild1

```
.bild1 {
```

This will bind the css on the img element inside class bild1

```css
.bild1 img {
    position:relative;
    top:500 px;
    max-width:50%;
    max-height:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bild1">
        <img src="http://cms.immoscout24.ch/media/1341/umzug-ostern.jpg">
    </div>
```